# Incoming Mtp3 Message for nonlocal dpc=1111. But RemoteSpc is not found

Tags: restcomm

I have setup my SCTP and M3UA links. It's working successfully.

I receive mtp3 messages from an HLR using SSN 6.

The restcomm log shows:

Rx : Ass=clientAssociation PayloadData [dataLength=120, complete=true, unordered=false, payloadProtocolId=3, streamNumber=4, data=
Start: 0 (0x00)  End: 119 (0x77)  Length: 120 (0x78)
00: 01 00 01 01 00 00 00 78  02 10 00 6E 00 00 04 8B | .......x ...n.... 
10: 00 00 05 0E 03 02 00 0A  09 81 03 0E 19 0B 12 06 | ........ ........ 
20: 00 11 04 72 48 01 10 12  06 0B 12 07 00 11 04 72 | ...rH... .......r 
30: 48 01 50 60 07 40 62 3E  48 04 03 FC 24 60 6B 1A | H.P`.@b> H...$`k. 
40: 28 18 06 07 00 11 86 05  01 01 01 A0 0D 60 0B A1 | (....... .....`.. 
50: 09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00  0E 03 6C 1A A1 18 02 01 | ........ ..l..... 
60: 5D 02 01 38 30 10 80 08  56 05 97 29 17 00 89 F1 | ]..80... V..).... 
70: 02 01 05 83 01 00 00 00  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- | ........
]

I get a warning: Incoming Mtp3 Message for nonlocal dpc=1111. But RemoteSpc is not found.

The issues I'm having is that the onSendAuthenticationInfoRequest method is not being called so I'm not receiving the unkown imsi.

Did a wireshark trace and receiving the GSM MAP message. Shows the invoke sendAuthenticationInfo and I can see the unkown imsi.

What can cause this? Is there something I'm missing, why is my onSendAuthenticationInfoRequest method not called with the message.

Kind Regards